# "Are there areas in which I have been doing well?"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I am asking for feedback from a peer at work. Is it grammatically correct to say

> "Are there areas in which I have been doing well? and are there areas in which I should improve?"

Or it is better to say

> "What are some areas you think I did well? and some areas in which I can improve?"

Comment: Both are good, it's just preference. I would use "What areas do I excel in? And, what areas do I need to focus on?" or something like that.

Comment: Sentence two is a bit clumsy.  *Did I do that area well?* is not a natural sounding sentence unless you're applying pesticide to a farm field (an actual physical area).  For areas that are not physical but are instead conceptual one *does well **in** the area*.  Sentence #1 is the better sentence.

Comment: Both sentences are NOT correct. "areas...I did" is not idiomatic. You need to add an "in." The first is good. But after "well" you need a capital "A."

Comment: @FearlessGrammar - *Areas I did* is idiomatic if you are talking about doing things to physical areas.  Did you mow the lawns on the Upper East Side and in SoHo (NYC neighborhoods)?  Yes, I did those areas this morning.

Comment: @EllieK sorry I didn't make myself clear. The the areas I was referring to is not a physical area. By areas I mean things like "project management skills"

Comment: @Joji - I understood you.  I was just pointing out that sometimes, in some situations, *areas I did* can be idiomatic.  FearlessGrammer makes a valid point about your use of *And* .  You should either capitalize the word *And* and make two correctly formed sentences or you should remove the first question mark and make one long compound sentence.  In many ways that decision is a decision of style.   I would suggest one long sentence with one question mark at the end.  You don't need to offset each questioning phrase with its own question mark.